# BI dashboard software

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence

I am a BusinessObjects Desktop Intelligence (XIR2) report developer and there is a need at my work for a dashboard showing measurements of the firm towards meeting budgets and trend analysis, etc.  I am seeking any input on suitable software (both paid and free) that will achieve this.

Ideally we would like the software to be integrated into a custom windows form application that we have developed (DotNet 3.0), so something that can be integrated into Visual Studio 2008 would be great, but if there are any recommendations for standalone applications that are forms or web based then this would be greatly appreciated.

We would want an application that makes use of traffic lights to highlight trouble areas, gauges (such as speedo), worm lines or similar trend visual representations.

I am an experienced report developer and am wanting to expand my knowledge into more statistics and visual analysis of data, so my knowledge of statistics is very green so I appologise in advance if I have mis-used any language.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You've not actually asked a statistics question. I would think that this question is probably better suited to SO? If you want to reword your question, feel free. Otherwise, I'll migrate it in a few hours.

Comment: My apologies, I hosetly thought that Business Intelligence and data visualisation was an element of statistics and thought that this community would be better suited then SO.  If it belongs in SO then please feel free to migrate it.

Comment: @Lima: It could be argued either way (and I would say we're fairly relaxed around here). However, I think you might get better answers at SO.

Comment: Have you already taken a look on visualizations which are provided by Business Objects, such as: Dashboards or Xcelsius?

Comment: @skarab: yeah, will look a little more seriously at it if cant find a better priced way of achieving it.  Were running XIR2, which I would love it if we were able to move to XIR3 next FY at which point we might look at the dashboard's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at Dundas components.  Looks like they have tight integration with .NET.
Business Objects also has a dashboard builder.  I am not sure why you are not using that if you already have the BO skills

http://support2.dundas.com/

-Ralph Winters

Comment: Thanks for that, we haven't really had a pressing need for a dashboard, and our PMS supplier has one that they sell (for something like 20k) so were just interested in the feasability of making our own that suits our needs. Ill check this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Our BI software is a Web-based server application, and it offers a high-degree of customization so I am pretty sure you'd be able to design the kind of dashboard you describe.

You can check out some examples and download a free eval at:

http://www.inetsoft.com/products/dashboard_examples/

Also, an InetSoft SE can give you personalized guidance on getting started.

Mark Flaherty